# Does sudoers file required to restart to take changes effect

Tags: linux

Does sudoers file  required to restart to take changes effect. If yes, then how we can restart? without resarting the system.

Comment: Restarting Linux is a very basic operation though... You might want to look at Linux basics.

Comment: @ionizer If a Linux server hosts a 24/7 service, such as a website, the owner may want to maximize uptime and thus avoid restarting Linux. In such a case, restarting only the services that really need restarting is beneficial.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your question is : "do I need to restart my machine if I add someone in the sudoers file ?" the answer is : No, you don't need to restart, the newly user added in the sudoers will be able to use `sudo` as soon as you save the file.